# Accessing global class of same name inside another namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces

In my project, I have a static class Const.cs used for storing Const variables.
eg.

```
public static class Const
{
  public const string EXAMPLE= "Example";
  .........
  .........
  // blah blah..
}
```

It is a global file, doesn't come under any namespace. Due to some specific requirements, I have to create another Const class with **same name** "Const", but this time under some other namespace (say **Namespace1.Class1.cs**)

```
public class Namespace1.Class1
{
  string test = Const.EXAMPLE;  // this line throws error by compiler

  public static class Const
  {
    ......
    ......
  }
}
```

The problem is : I am using Const.strExample constants inside the Namespace1.Class1.cs

So there is ambiguity issue. The compiler cannot identify the **Const.strExample** as I have declared second **Const** class inside **Namespace1.Class1.cs**.
Is there a way to resolve this somehow and retain the same name or I can't do that?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `global` namespace like below.

```
namespace Namespace1
{
    public class Class1
    {
      string test = global::Const.EXAMPLE;
      string test2 = Namespace1.Class1.Const.EXAMPLE;

      public static class Const
      {
        ......
        ......
      }
    }
}
```